# How to navigate to main page . net maui?

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, maui

I want to navigate to main page, but this code doesn't work. The code in View Model works when I want to navigate to another view, but when I want to navigate to main page I get error:

> System.Exception:Relative routing to shell is currently not supported. Try prefixing your uri with///:///MainPage`.

MainMenuViewModel:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public async void GoToMenuVM()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MainPage));
}
```

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
 
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ClassicModeView), typeof(ClassicModeView));        
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ChangeColorModeView), typeof(ChangeColorModeView));         
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs:

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>(); 
  
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();            
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainMenuViewModel>();                
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ClassicModeView>();            
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ClassicModeViewModel>();                
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ChangeColorModeView>();            
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ChangeColorModeViewModel>();
    
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="Clicer_Game.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Clicer_Game.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage"/>
    
</Shell>
```

This works

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async void MenuListViewSelectedItem(MainMenuModel e)
{
    switch (e.Name)
    {
        case "Classic":
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(ClassicModeView));
            break;

        case "Race light":
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(ChangeColorModeView)); 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=relative+routing+to+shell+not+supported+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I need your AppShell xaml and App cs. As well as what do you have currently in your navigation stack when trying to access it. You may have to call ".." , "//", or "///". Or it may be a matter of adding shellcontent in the xaml.

Comment: I uptated question.

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public async void GoToMenuVM()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../../route");
}
```

Comment: That's the only way you'll be able to do it. The MainPage cannot be used as a relative route, because you'd have the root page multiple times on the navigation stack which isn't supported.